# why plugins in Qt have .dll and .lib files?

Tags: qt, plugins

Plugins as I know are loaded at run time so they don't need .lib file and a .dll file is adequate to load them at run time. But when you create a plugin in Qt and compile it in, say Windows , you get a .dll file and a .lib file and some other files. The most amazing part of the story is that you don't need to link it to your program if want to use the plugin. So why is it necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the standard qmake way of building a shared library, which automatically outputs the import library as well.

Just because it's a plugin and can load it as a plugin, should not mean you can't use it as a library, because a dll is still a library, and plugin-related functions might be useful if exposed through the usual shared library interface.